# WP7 Game - rotate only some controls when orientation changed

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, canvas, orientation-changes

I'm making a simple WP7 game and I have a little problem with orientation changing. My gameboard looks like this:

[image]

And I need to rotate only the numbers when orientation changed. Is there any easy way to do it? The numbers are TextBlocks and lines are rectangles. Gameboard is Canvas (but I can use Grid as well).

Or i could exclude the canvas from automatic rotating and only redraw the numbers. But I don't know how to do it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`PlaneProjection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection.rotationx%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) should be fine:

```
<TextBlock.Projection>
  <PlaneProjection RotationZ="90"/>
</TextBlock.Projection>
```

Obviously this would apply the projection immediately, so you would need to create it in code (or try using `0` for the `Z` value and then changing that in code (possibility of this is a long shot)) based on the data provided (and within) the [`OrienationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientationchanged%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event handler, such as:

```
myTextBlock.Projection = new PlaneProjection { RotationZ = 90 };
```